# contenteditable - updating data-* attributes using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable, custom-data-attribute

I'm buliding some basic rich text editing functionality for a client using `contenteditable`. One of the features requires changing the value of `data-*` attributes of a button, e.g. `<button data-type="telephone">Text</button>`

I've created a minimal example below - this creates a `contenteditable` area, then jquery attempts to update the `<button>`, before printing the updated HTML to the `#output` div.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>contenteditable data-* test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="input" contenteditable>
  <p>Some text!</p>
  <button data-url="/go-somewhere">Button text!</button>
  <p>More text!</p>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="output" style="font-family: monospace;">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready( function(){

  // --- Update the button --- //

  // 1. Add new data attribute: data-new="test!"
  $( '#input button' ).data( 'new', 'test!' );

  // 2. Update existing data attribute: data-url="/somewhere-else"
  $( '#input button' ).data( 'url', '/somewhere-else' );

  // 3. Add a class
  $( '#input button' ).addClass( 'new-class' );

  // --- Display the updated content --- //

  $( '#output' ).html( 
    $( '#input' ).html().replace( /</g, '&lt;' ).replace( />/g, '&gt;' ) 
  );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The results are:

- jquery **fails** to add the new `data-new="test!"` attribute
- jquery **fails** to update the existing `data-url` attribute
- jquery *does* manage to add `class="new-class"` using addClass()

How can I add/update the data-* attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in
>   the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

So, to **add/update**, you use `.attr(attribute, value)`:

```
$( '#input button' ).attr( 'data-new', 'test!' );
$( '#input button' ).attr( 'data-url', '/somewhere-else' );
```

> Since jQuery 1.4.3, data-* attributes are used to initialize jQuery
>   data. An element's data-* attributes are retrieved the first time the
>   data() method is invoked upon it, and then are no longer accessed or
>   mutated (all values are stored internally by jQuery).

[Referece](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Ah yes, of course! So obvious I'm kicking myself for not thinking of it sooner... thank you @azametzin

Comment: ...though just spotted the 2nd line shoud read `$( '#input button' ).attr( 'data-url', '/somewhere-else' );` - the 1st argument to attr() is missing the 'data-' prefix :)